# find the class a better way - jquery

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I know my selector will have a class of level-1, level-2, level-3

I want to set the level based on this but my way feels a bit clunky? Is there a neater way to do this

```
if ( $level.hasClass('level-2')) {
    $levelValue= "level2";
}
if( $level.hasClass('level-3')) {
    $levelValue = "level3";
}

if ( $level.hasClass('level-4')) {
    $levelValue= "level4";
}
```

**edit: sorry my mistake**

Comment: Are you really trying to set level to level2 for all of the classes?? It looks like you made a mistake but I could be wrong if thats what you intended.... Also in your question you say it will have class level-1 to level-3 but in the code it does 2-4. Which do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if($level.is('.level-2, .level-3, .level-4')){
    $level = "level2";
}
```

This uses jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function and checks whether `$level` has any of the classes.

**Update:** Try using this:

```
if($level.is('[class^="level"]')){
    $levelValue = $level.attr('class').match(/level-[0-9]*/); // e.g. 'level-2'
}
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/rE3bL/1/

Comment: lovely - thanks very much, I need to get better at regular expressions.  Though it needs the wildcard in my code class*="level"

Answer (score 0):

Are there style rules associated with each level? If it's just data the I'd use a data attribute like `data-level='2'` then you can access this by using this jQuery function: `$level.data('level')`

Answer (score 0):

what is $level? a div?
if you want to set $level to "level1", "level2" and "level3" (not "level2" every time like in your code), you can use the data attr:

```
<div class="level1" data-level="1">
<div class="level2" data-level="2">
<div class="level3" data-level="3">
```

and your js is like:

```
$level = $level.data("level") //will return "1","2" or "3"
```

Comment: this would definately work but is a drupal menu and I cant access the data attribute.